# Как скачать и подключить jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу разобраться в подключении jQuery. Как её скачать? На официальном сайте не получается, выходит код на всю страницу и все…

Comment: сохраните этот код в файл .js (пкм - сохранить как)

Comment: Затем этот файл подключаете к вашему .html файлу: `<script src="имя-файла-с-jquery"></script>`

Comment: Зачем её вообще скачивать? Просто подключите из [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery).

Comment: Зачем её вообще скачивать? [х2] 2019 год на дворе, `jQuery` не нужен

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не все веб приложения для сетей, подключенных к интернету, как это не парадоксально =), хотя уверен на 99% автору Ваш совет как раз кстати

Comment: Спасибо большое))))

Answer (score 9):

Порядок действий такой (один из вариантов):

- Открываем любой текстовый редактор и создаём `html-файл`(расширение `.html`) с содержимым:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

- Сохраняем, с указанным выше расширением;
- Переходим на сайт [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) в раздел `jquery`;
- Выбираем версию (я выбрал `3.4.1`);
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- выбираем тип файла, я выберу сжатый (**minified**), кликаем по ссылке;
- Появится попап:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Копируем ссылку и вставляем в адресную строку броузера;
- После перехода нам откроется код (код `Jquery`). Сначала нажимаем
  комбинацию клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (выделить всё), затем
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (скопировать). Код у нас в буфере!

Теперь скопированный код можно добавить к нашему `html-файлу` двумя способами:

- Добавить тег `<script></script>` перед закрывающемся тегом `</body>` поместив между тегами код `Jquery`;
- Создать файл `.js` и поместить туда код `Jquery`. Затем подключить
  его, так же перед закрывающемся тегом `</body>`.

  > **UPD** для создания файла `.js` нажимаем комбинацию клавиш
  >   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> и сохраняем файл с указанным выше
  >   разрешением в папку с проектом (туда где вам проще подключить
  >   скрипт);

Для примера, я сформирую пример по первому варианту:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Т.к. снипет не позволив вставить код прямо сюда. -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Демонстрация того, что Jquery работает -->
  <div id="example"></div>

  <script>
    /*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
    /*! Сюда поместить скопированнй код */
  </script>

  <script>
    /*! Обязательно после подключения Jquery */
    $('#example').text('Ура! Мы подключили Jquery!');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> На практике код `JS` код отделяют от `html`. А `Jquery` подключают либо как отдельный файл, либо через `CDN`.

**Успехов в изучении**

Comment: Хороший мануал, но может стоить заменить [Ctrl+A Ctrl+C] на [Ctrl+S]?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Ну можно и сразу сохранить) Привычка.

Comment: Спасибо большое)))

Comment: @Maxim примите ответ

Comment: @doox911 как мне принять ответ?

Comment: @Maxim, зарегистрироваться и нажать галочку.